# How to run one exe by passing dynamic parameters using single bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have an requirement to run one EXE. It will take 7 parameters out of which one parameter is dynamic. Could some one help me how to run the EXE by passing dynamic parameters using bat file.

Thanks
Chaitanya

Answer (score 13):

If you need to execute a command with a dynamic number of parameters you can use `%*`.

#### Example Command:

```
foo.exe [options] <file1> <file2> ...
```

Say you wanted to have a batch script which sets some options but still passes a dynamic number of files

#### foo.bat

```
@ECHO OFF;
foo.exe -some -option %*
```

Running:

`foo.bat file1.txt file2.txt`

Translates To:

```
foo.exe -some -option file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run this :

```
my_7_param_program.exe p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7
```

With, say, p4 as a dynamic parameter, try this batch file:

```
@my_7_param_program.exe p1 p2 p3 %1 p5 p6 p7
```

and call it like this :

```
c:\> my_batch.bat 42
```

So the actual call will be

```
my_7_param_program.exe p1 p2 p3 42 p5 p6 p7
```

With the p1, p2, p3, p5, p6 and p7 hardcoded parameters.

Answer (score 2):

check this:
http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

The for command allows running commands with the result of another command.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the information provided. Will check and get back to u.

Comment: Dude, was it useful? I need some reps T_T