# Running .exe file with multiple parameters in c#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to start a .exe file which will ask further 4 different inputs but how can i pass these inputs as parameters. I have added these parameters as a string separated by a space in starting the new process but it didn't work? Could anyone help me to find out the solution?

```
String[] parms = { "1 1 Inputfile.cor Outputfile.dat" };
using (Process execProc = Process.Start("spi_sl_6.exe", String.Join(" ", parms)))
{
    execProc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Your string array contains a single element containing `1 1 Inputfile.cor Outputfile.dat`

Comment: Do you mean 1) you wish to pass these as command line arguments, or, 2) your executable starts and then asks you to plug values into text boxes or something?

Comment: Then, how to provide the required four elements?

Comment: I want to pass as command line arguments, not by asking that exe file

Comment: A quick search for spi_sl_6 shows that it's a program that does indeed pop up dialog boxes. You cannot magically put values in those dialogues by passing command line args if the app does not support it.

Comment: It may help you -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141542/how-to-run-one-exe-by-passing-dynamic-parameters-using-single-bat-file

Comment: I think you need to use something like Microsoft UI Automation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) to inject the values into those text boxes. It is a bit of work, but I believe it will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I made the solution. I created .bat file as follow:

```
(
echo 1
echo 1
echo Inputfile.cor
echo Outputfile.dat
) | spi_sl_6.exe
```

Then executed with

```
Process.Start("___.bat");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ProcesStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "spi_sl_6.exe";
psi.Arguments = "1 1 Inputfile.cor Outputfile.dat";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

**UPDATE:**
If I'm reading the comments above correctly, this won't help you. As it was said, there's no way to "automagically" plug values into the UI.