# How to call exe program and input parameters using R?

Tags: r, parameters, exe

I want to call .exe program (spi_sl_6.exe) using a command of R (system), however I can't input parameters to the program using "system". The followwing is my command and parameters:`system("D:\\working\spi_sl_6.exe")`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Try.jpg] 
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By 'input parameters' do you mean command line arguments or do you mean once you open the program those are things you would enter into the program?  The first situation is easy to deal with. The second... might not be possible unless the program is modified.

Comment: This doesnt seem (imo) an R question yet. Are you able to send the parameters to the exe program from the command line (sidestepping using R just now). If not, are oyu sure you can, as not all programs will facilitate this.

Comment: @Liangzhong; you need to make sure that the exe program has a facility to enter parameters at the command line. If you can do this, then you can pass it to a system call using R

Comment: @ Dason Thank you for your answer sincerely. I mean that five parameters are entered into the program once I open the program, just like the picture.

Comment: @ user20650; Thank you for your answer sincerely.  When I use the command  `system2("D:\\working\\SPI\\test\\spi_sl_6.exe")`,  I have no chance to input the parameters. Mybe I can't use R to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is using the Standardized Precipitation Index software from 
http://drought.unl.edu/MonitoringTools/DownloadableSPIProgram.aspx.

This seems to give a working solution using Windows (but not without warnings!)

Fisrt download the software and example files

```
# Create directory to download software
mydir <- "C:\\Users\\david\\spi"
dir.create(mydir)

url <- "http://drought.unl.edu/archive/Programs/SPI"
download.file(file.path(url, "spi_sl_6.exe"), file.path(mydir, "spi_sl_6.exe"), mode="wb")

# Download example files
download.file(file.path(url, "SPI_samplefiles.zip"), file.path(mydir, "SPI_samplefiles.zip"))
# extract one example file, and write out
temp <- unzip(file.path(mydir, "SPI_samplefiles.zip"), "wymo.cor")
dat <- read.table(temp)
# Use this file as an example input
write.table(dat, file.path(mydir,"wymo.cor"), col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

From page 3 of the help file *basic-spi-program-information.pdf* at the above link the command line code should be of the form `spi 3 6 12 <infile.dat >outfile.dat`, however, 
neither of the following worked (just from command line not in R), and various iterations of how to pass parameters.

```
C:\Users\david\spi\spi_sl_6 3 <C:\Users\david\spi\wymo.cor >C:\Users\david\spi\out.dat
cd C:\Users\david\spi && spi_sl_6 3 <wymo.cor >out.dat
```

However, using the accepted answer from  [Running .exe file with multiple parameters in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271417/running-exe-file-with-multiple-parameters-in-c-sharp)
seems to work. That is again from the command line

```
cd C:\Users\david\spi && (echo 2 && echo 3 && echo 6 && echo wymo.cor && echo out1.dat) | spi_sl_6
```

So to run this in R you can wrap this in a `shell` (you will need to change the path to where you have saved the exe)

```
shell("cd C:\\Users\\david\\spi && (echo 2 && echo 3 && echo 6 && echo wymo.cor && echo out2.dat) | spi_sl_6", intern=TRUE)
```

`out1.dat` and `out2.dat` should be the same.

This throws warning messages, I think from the `echo` (in R but not from command line) but the output file is produced.

Suppose you can automate all the echo calls sligtly, so all you need to do is input the time parameters.

```
timez <- c(2, 3, 6)
stime <- paste("echo", timez, collapse =" && ")
infile <- "wymo.cor"
outfile <- "out3.dat"
spiCall <- paste("cd", mydir, "&& (" , stime, "&& echo", infile, "&& echo", outfile, " ) | spi_sl_6")
shell(spiCall)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You have solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: I don't know about perfectly ;P, but you're very welcome. I added a full worked example to the answer, in the hope that it will make it easier for someone with more familiarity with Windows command line to offer suggestions to improve.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the command using `sprintf` :

```
cmd_name <- "D:\\working\spi_sl_6.exe"
param1 <- "a"
param2 <- "b"
system2(sprintf("%s %s %s",cmd_name,param1,param2))
```

Or using `system2`( I prefer this option):

```
system2(cmd_name, args = c(param1,param2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.  According to your advice, I construct the command using system2 `system2("D:\\working\\SPI\\test\\spi_sl_6.exe",args = c(2,3,6,"D:\\working\\SPI\\test\\Kita.cor","D:\\working\\SPI\\test\\restult.txt"))` However the exe programe can't work. The message is as follows "could not open output file" . In my limited experience with R ,I don't know why.